# Width parent same as floating divs

Tags: html, css

The goal is to make the cards div have the same width as the card children. So either the width of 1, 2 or 3 cards. The cards div also has to be centred on the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/xq69zL9e/

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="cards">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.card {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#cards {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 50px;
}

#cards:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: i am having a hard time understanding what it is that you want

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Something like this:

```
#cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

You can see an example [here](http://jsbin.com/rihacegava/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

you may use `display:table;` if i understood your question:
https://jsfiddle.net/xq69zL9e/2/

```css
.card {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#cards {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

> no need of a clearfix here nor width:)
>
> use of  `display`: `inline-flex`,`inline-table` or `inline-block` will do too but will require `text-align:center` on parent to center the container. no clearfix either there

Answer (score 0):

```
#cards {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: A little description is more helpful if you are posting an answer.